# Promise resolves too late in unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, firebase, angularfire

Unit testing an app using Firebase and angularFire. Mocking Firebase with [mockfirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase/).

In this test, the promise is resolved after the test is finished:

```
describe('the service api', function() {
    var promiseResolved;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // Inject with expected values
        _setup();
        promiseResolved = jasmine.createSpy('promiseResolved');
    });

    it('should resolve to a obj', function() {
        var obj = objService.getObjFromRefString('1234/q1w2');
        obj.$loaded().then(promiseResolved);
        obj.$ref().flush();
        expect(promiseResolved).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fails
    });
});
```

This approach seems to work for [the angularFire tests](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/tests/unit/FirebaseObject.spec.js) - see line 125.

If i use Jasmine async done feature:

```
        it('should resolve to a obj', function(done) {
            var obj = objService.getObjFromRefString('1234/q1w2');
            obj.$ref().flush();
            obj.$loaded().then(function() {
                console.log('resolved');
                promiseResolved();
                expect(promiseResolved).toHaveBeenCalled();
                done();
            });
        });
```

It fails with message "*Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL*".
The console.log is shown before.

The promise seems to resolve just after the timeout. I tried calling $rootScope.$apply() with no changes.

How can i make the promise resolve right away so the test can pass?

Comment: Shouldn't the $flush() go at the end? Anyway you will have to add the $rootScope.$apply(), too.

Comment: Have you checked if the promise really resolves with success? If it is rejected with error, `done` will not be invoked.

Comment: @lex82 A Firebase operation is queued when creating the obj. After that ref.flush() should be called. Doesn't change anything to move it to the end.

Comment: @boyomarinov Yes, the log is done and i checked promise.$$state.status was 1 in debugger. It resolves successfully, but right after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
$timeout.flush();
```

Updated test:

```
it('should resolve to a obj', function() {
    var obj = objService.getObjFromRefString('1234/q1w2');
    obj.$loaded().then(promiseResolved);
    obj.$ref().flush();
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(promiseResolved).toHaveBeenCalled(); // great success
});
```